# c++ twodimensional array passed to function

Tags: c++, arrays

I like to pass a two dimensional array to a function to print it.
Here is my code so far. As you can see on the comment it does not compile, because of an *incompatible type*.

*QUESTION*

How can I pass the two dimensional array to `printIt` ?
If I adjust it to `printIt(int a(*)[50][50])` I get the another error during compilation, because `returning array is not allowed`

```
using namespace std;

void printIt(int a[50][50]);

int main(int args, char *argv[]) 
{
    int a[50][50];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) 
    {
        a[i][j] = i;
        // the same should be printed out inside printIt
        cout << " " << a[i][j];
        // not compiling 
        // argument of type int is incompatible with int(*)[50]
        printIt(a[i][j]);
    }
}

void printIt( int a[50][50] )
{
    cout << " " << a[50][50];
}
```

Comment: You need to call `printIt(a);` .and `a[50][50];` is accessing the array out of bounds. I don't see any sense in what you're doing in your code. So what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: You see garbage values printed, not _"the memory location"_.

Comment: When I do a[50][50] the result is 7862380.

This is just a small learning thing here. I played around with two dimensional arrays and printed the result. So I thought, how can I extract that to a seperate function, but that is where I'm getting stuck

Comment: is `<<` really overloaded in such a way tha it can even dump a two dimensional array?  And if it were, would it understand not to dump stuff you have not initialized?  looks like a job for `std::vector` to me

Comment: I'd like to know, if someone is trying to get to know something new, and he asks here, why is this getting downvoted 4 times?

was this question unclear?
misleading?
or what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `a[i][j]` in an integer, it is a value. You are passing a value not an double array Your code should look like that :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printIt(int a)
{
    cout << " " << a;
}

int main(int args, char *argv[])
{
    int a[50][50];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        a[i][j] = i;
        // the same should be printed out inside printIt
        cout << " " << a[i][j];
        // not compiling
        // argument of type int is incompatible with int(*)[50]
        printIt(a[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah yes, I see, this is not an array I'm passing but an normal integer in this case. thanks!

Comment: Because you have an 2D array named a. What you are passing in parameters for `printInt()` is an integer, the value which is in the position `a[i][j]`. You are not passing an array but a value

Comment: You said "a[50][50] the result is 7862380", which is a value, an integer, not an array.  This is the same, you are giving a single value

Comment: No problem. Ask anything you want :)

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
int a[50][50];
```

`a[i][j]` evaluates to an `int`.

`a[i]` evaluates to `int [50]`, an array of `50` integers. If used as an argument to a function call, `a[i]` decays to a `int*` in most cases.  In rare cases it converts to `int (&)[50]`.

If used as an argument to a function call, `a` decays to `int (*)[50]` in most cases. In rare cases it converts to `int (&)[50][50]`.

In your case, the function declaration

```
void printIt(int a[50][50]);
```

is equivalent to

```
void printIt(int a[][50]);
```

and

```
void printIt(int (*a)[50]);
```

Hence, using

```
printIt(a);
```

is the right method of calling the function.

**However**

Given the way you are using the argument in `printIt`, you probably meant to use:

```
void printIt(int num)
{
   cout << " " << num;
}
```

After that, it OK to use:

```
printIt(a[i][j]);
```

in `main`.